# Can't access dev server when using ionic serve

Tags: localhost, docker, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use `ionic serve` to access a blank ionic template. It says it's working, but I just get 'page not found' in Chrome. I'm pretty confident that the ports are not the issue, since I can reach the live reload page on http://192.168.99.100:35729 and if I swap them, on http://192.168.99.100:8100.

nmap tells me:

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
8100/tcp closed xprint-server
```

I'm also using Docker. 192.168.99.100 is the IP of my VM.

```
Adrians-iMac:kosher_app Adrian$ docker run -p 8100:8100 -p 35729:35729 -v /Users/Adrian/Documents/current_projects/kosher_app/kosher:/ionic -i -t app serve
    Running dev server: http://localhost:8100
    Running live reload server: http://localhost:35729
    Watching : [ 'www/**/*', '!www/lib/**/*' ]
    Ionic server commands, enter:
      restart or r to restart the client app from the root
      goto or g and a url to have the app navigate to the given url
      consolelogs or c to enable/disable console log output
      serverlogs or s to enable/disable server log output
      quit or q to shutdown the server and exit
```

If it helps, here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM google/nodejs

WORKDIR /ionic
VOLUME ["/ionic"]
RUN npm install -g cordova ionic && ionic platform add android

EXPOSE 8100
EXPOSE 35729
ENTRYPOINT ["ionic"]
CMD ["serve"]
```

This is the result of `docker port` when applied to the container:

```
35729/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:35729 8100/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8100
```

Comment: Try to remove the -p 35729:35729 statement, i think you should use only one -p statement,otherwise the second may override the first one. It's the reason why you can access to livereload page, not the application page

Comment: I did try and remove that, but no success. That port mapping is part of the Docker container, and I think I need to do that to expose both ports. When I can run `ionic serve 35729 8100` to swap the ports `serve` is using.

Comment: according to the documentation, it seems the ionic command to invert ports is : `ionic serve -r 8100 -p 35729`, can you try it ?

Comment: That did invert the ports, but didn't fix the problem. I could access live reload on `8100`, but nothing on `35729` :/

Comment: what does `docker port` says ? you could have an hidden issue in the port configuration. see [docker port configuration](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports)

Comment: This is what docker port says:
`35729/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:35729
8100/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8100`.
I'll check if there is anything I missed on the port configuration page.

Comment: Does this till work for you? I just tried your solution (and plenty of others ) today and dont get it working. localhost is always not available for me. Just tried your Dockerfile (+ CMD ["sed -i 's/localhost/0.0.0.0/' /usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/serve.js"]). I have no idea, what's the problem. I'm using a Mac as well

Comment: For me worked this: '$ ionic serve --address=127.0.0.1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic has currently a problem listening/binding to 0.0.0.0. This is fixed in the new beta. There is a workaround mentioned in this thread:

source: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/322

My workaround was add this line on my Dockerfile:

`RUN sed -i 's/localhost/0.0.0.0/' /usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/serve.js`

Or in some cases (depending on the version):

`RUN sed -i 's/localhost/0.0.0.0/' /usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/serve.js`

Answer (score 0):

Try `npx cap sync`
for more info refer
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/basics/workflow#sync-your-project